# How to launch, monitor and kill a process in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, process, popen

I need to be able to launch a long-running process in Python.  While the process is running, I need to pipe the output to my Python app to display it in the UI.  The UI needs to also be able to kill the process.

I've done a lot of research.  But I haven't found a way to do all three of those things.

subprocess.popen() lets me start a process and kill it if I need to.  But it doesn't allow me to view its output until the process has finished.  And the process I am monitoring never finishes on its own.

os.popen() lets me start a process and monitor its output as it is running.  But I don't know of a way to kill it.  I'm usually in the middle of a readline() call.

When using os.popen(), is there a way to know if there is any data in the buffer before calling read() or readline?  For example...

```
output = os.popen(command)
while True:
    # Is there a way to check to see if there is any data available
    # before I make this blocking call?  Or is there a way to do a 
    # non-blocking read?
    line = output.readline()
    print(line)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for fine-grained control over processes.

```py
import subprocess


def main():
    try:
        cmd = ['ping', '8.8.8.8']
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            universal_newlines=True,
            bufsize=1,
            text=True
        )
        while True:
            print(process.stdout.readline().strip())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('stopping process...')
        process.kill()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- Setting `stdout` and `stderr` kwargs to `subprocess.PIPE` allows you to read the respective streams via `.communicate` instead of having them be printed to the parent's streams (so they'd appear in the terminal you ran the script in)
- `.kill()` allows you to terminate the process whenever you want
- `process.stdout` and `process.stderr` can be queried at any time to obtain their current line, via `readline()`, or an arbitrary amount of buffer content via `read()` or `readlines()`